# Make WebStorm Karma object and array output easier to read

Tags: karma-runner, webstorm

So, when I'm running tests in WebStorm with Karma (Just right-click on the karma.conf.js file and then select "run karma.conf.js.") it has a really nifty graphics user interface to sort through all the passing and failing tests, which is why I love it, but when you're testing an algorithm to sort through big arrays and objects the feedback when it fails is an awful blob:

```
> Expected [ [ Object({ id: 70111470, title: 'Die Hard', time: Object({
> type: 'End', time: 213432 }), url: Object({ width: 150, height: 200,
> url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg' }) }),
> Object({ id: 70111470, title: 'Die Hard', time: Object({ type:
> 'Start', time: 64534 }), url: Object({ width: 200, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg' }) }) ], [
> Object({ id: 654356453, title: 'Bad Boys', time: Object({ type: 'End',
> time: 54654754 }), url: Object({ width: 200, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg' }) }), Object({
> id: 654356453, title: 'Bad Boys', time: Object({ type: 'Start', time:
> 43524243 }), url: Object({ width: 140, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg' }) }) ], [
> Object({ id: 65432445, title: 'The Chamber', time: Object({ type:
> 'End', time: 132423 }), url: Object({ width: 130, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg' }) }),
> Object({ id: 65432445, title: 'The Chamber', time: Object({ type:
> 'Start', time: 54637425 }), url: Object({ width: 200, height: 200,
> url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg' }) }) ],
> [ Object({ id: 675465, title: 'Fracture', time: Object({ type: 'End',
> time: 45632456 }), url: Object({ width: 200, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg' }) }), Object({
> id: 675465, title: 'Fracture', time: Object({ type: 'Start', time:
> 234534 }), url: Object({ width: 120, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg' }) }), Object({
> id: 675465, title: 'Fracture', time: Object({ type: 'Middle', time:
> 3453434 }), url: Object({ width: 300, height: 200, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg' }) }) ] ] to
> equal [ Object({ id: 70111470, title: 'Die Hard', time: 323133, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg' }), Object({ id:
> 654356453, title: 'Bad Boys', time: 6575665, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg' }), Object({ id:
> 65432445, title: 'The Chamber', time: 3452343, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg' }), Object({
> id: 675465, title: 'Fracture', time: 323133, url:
> 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg' }) ].
```

Is there a plugin, setting, or simple hack that would make this more organized and easier to read?

Comment: Don't equal large objects on each other. Compare parts of the object, instead.

Comment: Well, that's a level-headed response. ...Still would be nice if I could make the parts neater. :D

Comment: You can probably over-ride the output methods for Karma upon launch with a simple piece of JavaScript. It probably uses `JSON.stringify` already; you would only need to add the pretty-print argument to it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've combed through preferences and I can't find configuration to 'pretty-print' it. For now, I'm breaking it up in textEdit, which isn't a bad way to study it. (Dealing with all that output really is helpful in spotting patterns.)